# How do you pattern match a DataDistribution

Tags: pattern-matching, probability-or-statistics

I have a function,

```
f[dist_, samp_]:=somework[dist, samp]
```

that I want to return `Null` or zero if passed a null distribution. I can't find a way to test for a difference between `Null` and Data distribution: none of  `===`, `=!=`, `SameQ` and `==` can identify them.

How can I tell if I'm being passed a `Null` value to handle it correctly?

```
f[dist_, samp_]:=something[dist, samp] /; TrueQ[dist==DataDistribution]
```

Seems to be close to what I want.

EDIT: Edited for some clarity.

Here's my function. If probKern is a Null, I want to return a Null, otherwise, I want to calculate the PDF for the sample, with the distribution. I can't quite get a handle on matching the types to make this work though.

```
calcPDF[probKern_, samp_] := 
 Null /; TrueQ[probKern != DataDistribution]

calcPDF[probKern_Symbol, samp_] := 
 PDF[probKern, samp] /; TrueQ[probKern == DataDistribution]
```

edit: Okay, I'm still having trouble with this. Here's what I have:

```
calcPDF[probKern_DataDistribution, samp_] := PDF[probKern, samp]  
calcPDF[Except[_DataDistribution, probkern_?DistributionParameterQ], samp_] := -1 
calcPDF[_] := $Failed
```

Given a data distribution and a value it works fine.

```
In[38]:= calcPDF[data, 3]

Out[38]= 0.007500611755
```

Given two numbers, it produces the symbolic value, rather than the -1 I was expect. (The -1 is just a placeholder)

```
In[39]:= calcPDF[3, 3]

Out[39]= calcPDF[3, 3]
```

EDIT dec 5th:
Running calcPDF by hand seems to result in correct results, but now, when it is threaded over data, the result is a single result of whatever you return in the Except case. There's two sets of distributions I'm running over the sample data, so the final result is a list of two Nulls (or -1's).

If you remove the Except case, you get closer to the expected result - two lists 205 elements long, containing PDF's for entries with matching Distributions, and PDF[Null, value] for those without.

I'm confused.

Clear[calcPDF]
(*calcPDF[probKern_, samp_]:=PDF[probKern, samp];
*)
calcPDF[probKern_DataDistribution, samp_] := PDF[probKern, samp];
calcPDF[Except[*DataDistribution], samp*] := Null;

(* Pass a list of samples, and a list of distributions's *)

applyKernel[lsamples_, kernel_] := Thread[calcPDF[kernel, lsamples]];

(* Pass a list of samples, and a list of two lists of distribution's *)

predClass[samples_, kernels_] := 
  Map[applyKernel[samples, #] &, kernels]; 
predPDF = predClass[predictionSamples[[1]], kernels]

Comment: What is a null distribution?

Comment: f[dist_, samp_]:=something[dist, samp] /; TrueQ[dist==DataDistribution]

Seems to do the trick. if my function isn't passed a valid Data Distribution it falls through to the default case.

Comment: Your question is a bit cryptic. Do you mean perhaps that you want to test whether `dist` is either a distribution that belongs to your null hypothesis or a `DataDistribution`? For comparing distributions we have `DistributionFitTest`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking to test whether dist is a DataDistribution or otherwise (I'm passing null myself). If it's a data distribution, I want to use it in a PDF. Otherwise, I want to pass on a Null value.

as it stands when mathematica comes across the Null value, it passes on PDF[Null, some value].

Comment: Steven, you can format blocks of code by selecting them and pressing the `{ }` button above the text box while editor your post.  See [Editing Help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more.

Comment: You need to change your second line to `calcPDF[Except[_DataDistribution], samp_] := -1` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are wanting something like the following.

For a function that does something with a `DataDistribution` something else with any other distribution and otherwise fails we would do.

```
f[dist_DataDistribution]:= "do stuff"
f[Except[_DataDistribution, dist_?DistributionParameterQ]]:= "do other stuff"
f[_]:= $Failed
```

Now if you want to match a particular `DataDistribution`, say `KernelMixtureDistribution` you will need to give it that information in your pattern.

```
g[dist:DataDistribution["KernelMixture",___]]:= "do stuff"
g[Except[_DataDistribution, dist_?DistributionParameterQ]]:= "do other stuff"
g[_]:= $Failed
```

**Edit:**

I believe your confusion comes from what `==` is doing in your checks.  When you try `dist == DataDistribution` you are asking if a particular object `dist` is the symbol `DataDistribution`.  What you really want to know is whether the `Head` of `dist` is `DataDistribution`.

**Edit 2:**

Lets say you wanted to use this approach to compute `CDF` for distributions returning `-1` if the computation isn't possible. You could set this up as.

```
cdf[dist_?DistributionParameterQ, x_]:= CDF[dist,x]
cdf[_,x_]:= -1
```

If you want separate treatment for `DataDistribution` say you can do that as well. Here I'm telling it to report what type of distribution was used and return the expression and -1 if it isn't a distribution.

```
cdf[dist_DataDistribution?DistributionParameterQ, x_]:= {dist["Type"], CDF[dist,x]}
cdf[dist_?DistributionParameterQ, x_]:= {Head[dist], CDF[dist,x]}
cdf[notAValidDist_, x_]:= {notAValidDist, -1}
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I want to do. At a later time I'll be doing different things based on the distribution. But for now, just answering the question is this a distribution or not gets me 95% of the way there.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. What you have looks like it should work, but in test cases it doesn't. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something though.

Comment: Is there any way to make a fallthrough for not a distribution, rather than matching specific types (like numericQ). I thought of matching Numeric, string, etc but that seemed like a hacky way to go.

Comment: This is what I have in the end. It seems far too messy for what it should be. There's no negation in the type pattern matching available is there? Something like ?!DataDistribution?


calcPDF[probKern_DataDistribution, samp_] := PDF[probKern, samp] 
calcPDF[probKern_?NumericQ, samp_] := -1
calcPDF[probKern_?StringQ, samp_] := -1
calcPDF[probKern_?ListQ, samp_] := -1

Comment: Yes, that is too messy.  If you want it to return -1 for anything that isn't a `DataDistribution` just replace your last 3 definitions with `calcPDF[Except[_DataDistribution],samp_]:= -1`.

Comment: Another comment about my solution, is it doesn't cover all the types i'm getting passed through. In particular sqldatetime. Ideally I'd like a two line solution one for valid datadistributions, and another fallthrough for not-datadistributions. But I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: This seems to get correct results in a scratch notebook. I Clear the function, but in my actual code, when threaded over 205 values, it returns a value of -1. I've updated my question with an example.

Comment: I think I'm very close to getting the expected result. I'm just missing some understanding of some detail of Mathematica somewhere. I do appreciate the patience and help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6632/discussion-between-andy-ross-and-steven)